# fail to pip3 install html==1.16

Tags: pip, python-3.11

I want to use this library: https://pypi.org/project/html/
which is not the default python library.

```
from html import HTML
h = HTML()
```

However it fails to install:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.3

$ pip3 --version 
pip 23.1.2 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

$ pip3 install html      
Collecting html
  Using cached html-1.16.tar.gz (7.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/d4/j5v02byx23g3bmrqrx7s1my80000gn/T/pip-install-ocf9gq9s/html_ae9a6942d7c44ed1ba82438e0f3af955/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
          long_description = __doc__.decode('utf8'),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this library is outdated from 2011, and even if the project page says it's compatible with python3, I guess it's not working. I wished the author would have added a warning on the project page, so we don't loose our time with outdated libraries.
https://pypi.org/project/html/

I am currently using this other library, updated this year, which it also allows creating html files, and it's working.
https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Comment: Note also that `html` is now a module in the stdlib https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html - with different functionality, but you would have run into issues shadowing a stdlib module anyway